# Find array value based on different array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Not sure how I had to describe the title, but my current problem looks like this:

I have two arrays, one looks like this (including surrounding code):

```
$element = $html->find('table',3); 
        $i = 0; 
        foreach($element->find('tr') as $row){ 
        if($i >= 2){ 
          $lapno = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;  
          $tyre = $row->find('td',3)->plaintext; 

          $racelap[$i] = Array(); 
          $racelap[$i][0] = $lapno; 
          $racelap[$i][1] = $tyre; 
        } 
          $i+=1;
    }
```

And the second array looks like this, also within a (different) `foreach` statement:

```
$stop[$i] = Array(); 
          $stop[$i][0] = $pitno; 
          $stop[$i][1] = $pitlap;
```

Now I have to add this part from the first array: `$racelap[$i][1] = $tyre;` to `$pitstop[$i][2]` in the second array. I've tried to do it like this, but it didn't work:

`$racelap[$stop[$i][1]][1]`

for example `$stop[1][1]` has to show the result of `$tyre` in the specific pitlap.

Hope I explained it well enough and someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that $racelap is an array index by $i and not by $lapno.
if you replace numeric index array by an associative array like that :

```
$racelap[$lapno]=$tyre;
```

you can do :

```
$pitstop[$i][2]=$racelap[$stop[$i][1]];
```